# PayPal Sandbox Accounts Blank

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

**Accounts I create through the PayPal sandbox (created on http://developer.paypal.com/) are created with zero balance and no credit card regardless of what I set when creating the account**.

This results in:
On payment page, a request for me to enter a credit card for the account
No paypal balance (tested by logging into the paypal sandbox).

I have tried creating multiple accounts, several with balances of `$3,000` USD, one with a credit card set, another with paypal set, and always with credit card type of Visa. Always they are created blank.

**Is this a PayPal related problem, or am I not creating sandbox accounts correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to reproduce this issue and PayPal is working to resolve it right now. I will reply back as soon as this is fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks! Glad you guys are active on SO.

Comment: We are still working to get this fixed. Sorry to keep you waiting, I will have more information for you soon.

Comment: Fixed yet? Really need this!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, we are still working to resolve this issue. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: We are currently rolling out a fix to address this issue. As we continue to apply this fix, you will have intermittent success in creating new SB accounts. Once we finish rolling out the fix, the issue should be resolved. I will confirm once this is completely resolved.

Comment: Can you please attempt to create a test account now and let me know if you run into any issues? This issue should now be resolved.

Comment: @PayPal_Jared Please help me for the same , i have created a sandbox buyer account with zero balance, but at app "send payment" it works, how? As i don't have balance for that logged buyer account , it should not do transaction. importantly amount getting credited to seller account. how ? please explain me if i am missing something.

Comment: this is still happening as of 2016