# PayPal - Sandbox - Created Test Accounts Have Zero Balance

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to integrate PayPal payment with Drupal which entails creating Developer/Sandbox accounts. I've created Personal and Business testing accounts in my PayPal Developer dashboard and set their initial balances and tried $1,000,000, $1,000, or $100 values. However, when I logged in to their corresponding Sandbox accounts, it still indicates a $0.00 balance. I've tried creating other Gmail and PayPal accounts to create other testing accounts, but the result is the same.

Also, I've resorted to creating test accounts since when I tried clicking/editing the **Profile** link in the **default** test accounts (to try to see their passwords/edit their default balances), the opened modal window will be in an indefinite "processing.." state.

Hence, it seems that there are at least 2 issues for the test accounts: **Profile** link not loading/rendering and initial balances are being reset or not being propagated to their target Sandbox accounts (the latter is more important I guess).

Furthermore, a similar issue happened 3 years ago: [PayPal Sandbox Accounts Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481509/paypal-sandbox-accounts-blank)

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed by PayPal. Please go ahead for your testing.
If you still have the issue, please delete old test accounts and re-create new ones.

Comment: indeed, we had same problem but now everything works again

Comment: I could confirm that it's now working/resolved. I created new Gmail and PayPal accounts just to make sure. Turned out that the **Profile** link is now working in the Test Buyer/Facilitator accounts so I don't need to create new test accounts anymore (and the default Test Buyer also has an initial $9999 balance which is quite handy). I tried changing the default Test Buyer account's password and it's working as intended when I login in the PayPal Sandbox. Thanks a lot.