# Paypal sandbox and strange issue when try to access Account Details

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Well i've created a paypal account then tried to use sandbox accounts, paypal creates two accounts: -facilitator and -buyer ...

I don't know password of these accounts but i figured out that it should be show in Account Details popup but not, look this pic:

[image]

maybe i'm missing something ? any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, PayPal Sandbox is currently not working and several others have the same issues. Check the 'paypal-sandbox' tag here to see the issues of the other users.

We just have to hope that PayPal fixes this issue asap. Maybe contact the support so that they will put this issue on high priority.

Comment: hum understand it, well is there a way to test my code? a alternative way?

Comment: I tried it several times to create a new account and with some luck I got a halfway working account and could get the API keys for the Sandbox.

Maybe try it several times and keep contacting PayPal support to fix the issue.

Another way is to create a second PayPal business account and using the normal API. There you can test your could, however, you transfer then real money between your two accounts. I don't know if you can refund the transfered money and by this avoid to paying the fee charged by PayPal. Maybe someone knows more about, if you can refund also the fees?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I've posted a question few hours ago. No response from BugPal, someone has solved? Anyway one suggestion: I've created a "corrupted" account (has paypal says after creation) simple inserting a text into "Note" field.

Comment: @Awsj2hd8 I've posted a solution to my own question after few experiments, I hope this can helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703774/unable-to-use-sandbox-accounts/38716835#38716835

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar/related issue last week, and it had been resolved by PayPal since August 3: [PayPal - Sandbox - Created Test Accounts Have Zero Balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683748/paypal-sandbox-created-test-accounts-have-zero-balance)